# Navigation drawer inflate exception when running on Tablet

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am implementing navigation drawer in my application by using.

```
 <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/card6"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/card6"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/drawermenu"
    android:layout_gravity="start">

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

It is running perfectly in mobile devices with Android 6.0 or above but while running it in Tablet which is also running on Android 6.0 it gives runtime inflate Exception.

```
   Binary XML file line #160: Binary XML file line #160: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.radiant.rpl.testa.Initials.Welcome_page.onCreate(Welcome_page.java:82)
```

I am not able to understand what might be the issue in this.

Comment: check for issues in header layout and the drawermenu

Comment: and check the line 160

Comment: post your activity and layout file

Comment: Thanks. I have solved it. The issue was in Header layout. The icon was causing issues.